# "UIViewController subclass" does not appear in file template library for xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.3

I am fairly new to XCODE development currently following several tutorials.

Bumped into an unexpected problem - looking for help!

The problem is that the "UIViewController subclass" does not appear in the file template library.
My book and every page I checked has this template under iOS or Mac "Cocoa touch" category.
My xcode only shows "Objective-C Class" "Objective-C Category" "Objective-C Class Extension" "Objective-C protocol" "Objective-C Test Case Class"

How can I add a new file template of UIViewController subclass ?

My environments:
- Snow Leopard
- xcode version: 4.3

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Choose `objective-c class` and then select `UIViewController` as subclass.

Apple moved all objective-c class templates into the "Objective-C class" template. 
They have custom functionality, like "With xib for user interface", there too.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why Apple change many things often. Most of tutorial I found on the net are to old with the change from Apple.

Comment: Yes, if you following online tutorial this makes things harder.